# Box goes in front of text

Tags: html, css

So I am pretty new to HTML and CSS 's stuff and I'm trying to get my text in front of my transparent box. The problem is it goes behind it and no matter what I try it stays behind it. I tried it with a placeholder (the lorem ipsum thing or whatever) and worked fine, but as soon as a place an H1 tag my whole text magically goes behind the box. Like, what? So I added h1 in my CSS and it somehow changed the proportions of my box? What?
Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="description" conten="The super cool website from the idiot names kawaiinacho. Seriously why do you even bother this place?" />
<title>Kawaiinacho's super cool website!</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icon.ico">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topbar"></div>
    <nav class="sidebarleft">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><div>Home</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><div>Placeholder</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><div>Placeholder</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><div>Placeholder</div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="text">
        <p><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam nibh. Nunc varius facilisis eros. Sed erat. In in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet. Curabitur adipiscing luctus massa. Integer ut purus ac augue commodo commodo. Nunc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer. Etiam vitae nisl. In dignissim lacus ut ante. Cras elit lectus, bibendum a, adipiscing vitae, commodo et, dui. Ut tincidunt tortor. Donec nonummy, enim in lacinia pulvinar, velit tellus scelerisque augue, ac posuere libero urna eget neque. Cras ipsum. Vestibulum pretium, lectus nec venenatis volutpat, purus lectus ultrices risus, a condimentum risus mi et quam. Pellentesque auctor fringilla neque. Duis eu massa ut lorem iaculis vestibulum. Maecenas facilisis elit sed justo. Quisque volutpat malesuada velit.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

and the main.css

```
html {
    min-width: 980px;
}
body {
    background-color:#292929;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.topbar {
    width: 1920px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    border: 0px;
    color: #AB0000;
    border-bottom: 1px #000000;
    background-color: #AB0000;
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 2px;
}
.sidebarleft {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px 50px 20px 40px;
    border: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    float: left
}
.sidebarleft li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
.sidebarleft a {
    background: #AB0000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
}
.sidebarleft a:hover {
    background: #292929;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.text {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 26px;
    border: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.text p {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

the website is here tho http://kawaiinacho.xyz/
I tried z-index, every position thing there is, switching the code arround. Nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Box is not transparent its black, so if you add `color: white;` on that div you will see text.

Comment: Side note, you have a `</div>` between your closing body and html tags.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have problem on HTML - `h1` is inside `p` tag, must be:

   ```
   <h1>THis is heading</h1>
   <p>This is paragraph</p>
   ```
2. Then try change color using CSS:

   ```
   .text {
       color: #fff;
   }
   ```
3. Delete `</div>` after `</body>` tag!

Answer (score 0):

The text isn't behind the box, it's just that your text is the same color as the box! Add this css and you'll clearly see the text (and be able to select/highlight it too):

```
body {color:white;}
```